# Python: extracting arrays from DataFrame column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to extract data from DataFrames as individual NumPy arrays to pass to SciPy stats methods.

Example DataFrame:

```
userId  numCol
147     1.3 
222     2.6
389     5.7 
443     1.2 
222     2.4
678     2.1
443     1.8
501     2.1
147     1.2
501     3.2
678     1.3
389     2.4
```

For the 6 unique userId's, let's say I only want to extract 4 separate arrays for the values of `numCol` for the userId's 147, 222, 389 and 443.

The output would look like this:

Array name 147: `array([1.3, 1.2)]`
Array name 222: `array([2.6, 2.4)]`
Array name 389: `array([5.7, 2.4)]`
Array name 443: `array([1.2, 1.8)]`

I'm wondering if the best approach would be to create a list for the userId's I want, then loop through the DataFrame utilising pandas `isin` and NumPy `values`.

I've looked at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957112/extract-array-column-name-data-from-pandas-dataframe) closely and it's not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the rows corresponding to a particular userId with something like `df[df.userId == 147]`.  So if you have a list of userIds you want, you could do something like:

```
for userId in userIds_to_check:
    stats.anderson(df[df.userId == userId].numCol)
```

(or whatever function you want to call instead of `anderson`).  Note that usually you don't need to get a plain numpy array; you can call most stats functions on a pandas Series and they'll work just fine.  If you do want a plain numpy array for some reason, you can do `df[df.userId == userId].numCol.values`.

Depending on what you're doing, you may want to just use `groupby`, which would allow you to just map a function onto every userId group, something like:

```
>>> df.groupby('userId').numCol.apply(stats.skew)

userId
147    0.000000e+00
222    0.000000e+00
389    3.954380e-16
443    0.000000e+00
501   -1.251190e-15
678   -8.673617e-16
Name: numCol, dtype: float64
```

Here I computed the skewness of the numCol values for every userId all in one fell swoop by applying `stats.skew` to each group.

Comment: Brilliant answer, learnt so much! Would you mind just adding how to also extract the individual arrays, as I would like to have the flexibility depending on what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan: The individual array is the `df[df.userId == blah].numCol`, where `blah` is whatever userId you want the values of.

Comment: Thanks again - but the original idea was to extract the individual arrays through an iterative process, not just extract them one at a time. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Jonathan: Then just do what I did in my example with the `for` loop but remove the call to `stats.anderson`.  That is: `for userId in userIds_to_check: do_whatever_you_want_with(df[df.userId == userId].numCol)`

Comment: I'm having trouble with this. Very precisely, I need to know what code to use to return numpy arrays where you have written `do_whatever_you_want_with`. I have tried all sort of things like `values` and `as.array`. I need you to spell it out if possible.

Comment: `for userId in userids_to_check: df[df.userId == userId].numCol.values` .  But you cannot "return" something from a `for` loop.  You have to *do* something with each value in the loop.  Do you want to accumulate the numpy arrays into a list?  If you are having trouble, please edit your question to say what exactly you want to happen to each numpy array, show the code you're using, and say what it's not doing that you want it to do.

Comment: I'd been using the for loop inside of a function but initially couldn't get the output I wanted, but got there in the end. I also used the other methods you detailed as well today, so all good. Thanks for persisting with this.